# Android: how to check if an intent broadcast happens?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

Currently I'm developing and alarm clock. I'm using AlarmManager and a Receiver to catch alarms.

However my broadcast receiver is stopped to trigger during development process and I want to know are there any debug tools or adb commands to check which intents are broadcasted in android OS or not?

I want to use it for debug purpose to make sure my intent is broadcasting.

Comment: One way is to write a test using Espresso. See intended() method.